# Añadir información gráfico en python

Tags: python, matplotlib

Me gustaría poder añadir la fecha sobre cada columna generara.
    La información la tengo en el siguiente data frame (df_total)

```
 [num_ejec,  servidor,    t_medio,    fecha,]
 [2,   slnxdes1,    0.04, 2020-01-27]
 [1,   slnxdes1,   0.09,  2020-01-29]
 [4,    slnxdes1,     0.04,    2020-01-30]
 [3,    slnxdes1,     0.03,    2020-01-31]
 [1,    slnxdes1,     0.03,    2020-02-03]
 [1,    slnxdes2,     0.04,    2020-01-27]
```

La gráfica que obtengo mediante matplotlib es:

```
df_total[['num_ejec','servidor','t_medio']].plot(kind='bar',x='servidor',y='t_medio',color= 'blue'],stacked = False,figsize=(10,10),fontsize=15)
```

Me genera un gráfico de barras

Y como comento necesito añadir la fecha sobre cada columna.

Gracias por vuestra ayuda.
  un saludo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero obtienes los ejes (`ax`) al hacer el plot y despues iteras sobre el objeto ax.patches y vas anotando el valor que necesitas uno a uno:

```
ax = df_total[['num_ejec','servidor','t_medio']].plot(kind='bar',x='servidor',y='t_medio',color= 'blue',stacked = False,figsize=(10,10),fontsize=15)

for i, p in enumerate(ax.patches):
    ax.annotate(df_total.loc[i, 'fecha'], (p.get_x() * 1.01, p.get_height() * 1.01))
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]